# Input showing as a select with cake form helper

Tags: php, cakephp, select, input, form-helpers

I have the following code:

```
<h2>Add System</h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('ReleaseServer');
echo $this->Form->input('server_name',array('error'=>array(
                           0 => 'Please choose a system name'),
                          'label'=>'System Name'
            ));
echo $this->Form->input('server_id', array('label'=> 'System ID'));
echo $this->Form->select('server_environment', $environments, null, array(
                                'empty' => "-- Select an Environment --",
                                'label' => "Select an Environment",
                                'error' => array(0 => 'Please choose an environment!'),
                                'onchange'=>'console.log(this.value);'
                            )
                        );
echo $this->Form->end('Save System');
?>
```

For some reason the line
`echo $this->Form->input('server_id', array('label'=> 'System ID'));`
shows up as a select box no matter where I place it.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding [`type` to your options array](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1392/options-type) and explicitly defining what you want the input to be.

**Edit**

After digging around in the Cake API I think I may have found a specific line of code that may be affecting you here.

```
if (preg_match('/_id$/', $fieldKey) && $options['type'] !== 'hidden') {
    $options['type'] = 'select';
}
```

It appears likely that you are triggering this `if` conditional.  If so, your only option is to explicitly set the `type` attribute in your options array.

Comment: that is what I did, but for some reason on the other input I do not have to do that.

Comment: yep, that was the issue. it is because the column name is `*_id` because of that it thinks i should be picking from another table -- thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am using a hack:

```
echo $this->Form->input('server_id', array('label'=> 'System ID',
                                           'type'=>'text'));
```

I am explicitly setting the `type` as text.

I do not have to do that for the other input, but that might be the way it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the input if it doesn't matter to show or not. As when inserting mysql will assign it a new id.

```
    echo $this->Form->input('server_id', array('type'=> 'hidden'));
```